# Trouble Executing ffprobe Binary in Node.js on Local Machine

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, aws-sdk, ffprobe

I'm facing an issue executing the `ffprobe` binary within a Node.js script on my local machine. I have a Node.js script that uses the `fluent-ffmpeg` library to extract video metadata using `ffprobe`. While I can execute the `ffprobe` binary directly from my terminal and retrieve the expected output, I'm encountering issues when attempting to run it within my Node.js script.

**Project Structure:**

```
project-root/
├── assets/
│   └── video.mp4
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   └── index.js
├── layers/
│   └── ffmpeg/
│       └── ffprobe   <-- This is the binary I'm trying to execute
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
```

**Example Code:**

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const binaryPath = './layers/ffmpeg/ffprobe';

exec(binaryPath, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Command executed successfully');
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.error('stderr:', stderr);
});
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error: Command failed: ./layers/ffmpeg/ffprobe
./layers/ffmpeg/ffprobe: ./layers/ffmpeg/ffprobe: cannot execute binary file
```

**Troubleshooting:**

1. Ensured that the `ffprobe` binary has executable permissions using `chmod +x`.
2. Verified that the architecture of the `ffprobe` binary is arm64, which matches my local system.
3. Checked that the path to the binary is correct and doesn't contain special characters.
4. Tested the basic execution of `ffprobe` using the `exec` function, but it still fails.

---

I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including verifying permissions, checking the architecture, and testing basic execution. Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to execute the `ffprobe` binary within the Node.js environment. I expected the script to successfully run the `ffprobe` binary and provide the expected output, just like when I run the binary directly from the terminal.

Could anyone provide insights into why the `ffprobe` binary fails to execute within the Node.js environment, even though it works perfectly when executed from the terminal? Are there any additional considerations I might be missing?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `fluent-ffmpeg` docs on the NPM page, it seems it's pretty simple to run `ffprobe` on a video file.

Assuming `ffprobe.exe` is on your `PATH`, their example code should print metadata:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.ffprobe('./assets/file.mp4', function(err, metadata) {
    console.dir(metadata);
});
```

Not sure why you're trying to execute directly the binary. I understand that you should use the Node library as a worker layer.

If you need a custom `ffprobe` binary, they provide `setFfprobePath()` to set its location. But I suppose it has to be an `.exe`.

Comment: I believe my question is not accurate. This pertains to calling a function in AWS Lambda. Lambda cannot execute this function because it is unable to read the binary file. Nevertheless, the issue has been resolved by recompiling that binary file for the Amazon Linux OS.